# Multiple spans in same String

Tags: android, textview, spannable

I've got problems to set StyleSpan and ForegroundColorSpan in the same string. Here's my code:

```
SpannableStringBuilder text_1_2 = new SpannableStringBuilder(getString(R.string.why_text_1_2));

StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.custom_blue));

text_1_2.setSpan(fcs, 0 , text_1_2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
text_1_2.setSpan(bss, 0, text_1_2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

The resulting string has blue color but is not bold.

Thanks.

Comment: Can we have desired String output ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this

```
text_1_2.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0 , text_1_2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
text_1_2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.custom_blue)), 0, text_1_2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

But my recommendation is if you don't want to style a part of the string apply the style and color using

```
 android:textColor="@color/color_name"
 android:textStyle="bold"
```

Comment: The problem is have to use 3 different styles on same text, and i'm using `TextUtils.concat()` for the 3 different Strings. The first code you put works for me. Thanks for editing the answer.

Comment: great.. then 1st option should be fine